# How to remove Vertex in JGraphX lib?

Tags: java, swing, jgraphx

I'm trying to solve a task where i need to display graph in Swing. Found [JGraph](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) framework (which is now called JGraphX). In samples the `graph.insertVertex(...)` method is used for adding Vertices and the `graph.insertEdge(...)` method for Edges - ok it works fine.

But how can i remove that Vertex afterwards?

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you can use the `mxGraph.removeCells` method for removing a vertex. I have modified the [HelloWorld](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/blob/master/examples/com/mxgraph/examples/swing/HelloWorld.java) example that is included in [JGraphX](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx) (using release [3.4.1](https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/releases/tag/v3.4.1.0)):

```
import com.mxgraph.swing.*;
import com.mxgraph.view.*;
import javax.swing.*;

/**
 * Adapted from https://github.com/jgraph/jgraphx/blob/master/examples
 *              /com/mxgraph/examples/swing/HelloWorld.java
 */
public class GoodbyeVertex extends JFrame {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -2707712944901661771L;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        GoodbyeVertex frame = new GoodbyeVertex();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setSize(400, 320);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public GoodbyeVertex() {
        super("Hello, World!");

        mxGraph graph = new mxGraph();
        Object parent = graph.getDefaultParent();

        graph.getModel().beginUpdate();
        try {
            Object v1 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "Hello", 20, 20, 80, 30);
            Object v2 = graph.insertVertex(parent, null, "World!", 240, 150, 80, 30);

            graph.insertEdge(parent, null, "Edge", v1, v2);

            // Remove a vertex. The related edge is removed as well.
            graph.removeCells(new Object[]{v1});
        } finally {
            graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }

        mxGraphComponent graphComponent = new mxGraphComponent(graph);
        getContentPane().add(graphComponent);
    }
}
```